# Dynamic client using JaxWsDynamicClientFactory (Apache CXF)

Tags: java, web-services

I want to make a dynamic client to invoke the web service that I created. I tried using `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` as mentioned in its official [site](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) but I am not getting any ouput. Instead, I am getting `NullPointerException`.

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client c = dcf.createClient("http://localhost:8080/service/SearchingSEI?wsdl");
```

The second line is throwing the exception.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.useJava6Compiler(Compiler.java:189)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:143)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.compileJavaSrc(DynamicClientFactory.java:599)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:235)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:183)
    at com.client.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.main(DynamicClientFactory.java:24)
```

I have no idea what the problem is. Any suggestions would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an old version of Java?

Comment: @artbristol Also tried on 7. But still no luck.

Comment: Are you running the code on a JRE or a JDK?

Comment: Of course JRE executes the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the code using a JDK, not a JRE. The NPE is happening in the following bit of CXF's `Compiler` class

```
   JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
   StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
```

`compiler` is null if you run in a JRE.

Comment: You need to *run* the code with a JDK. Bear in mind, some IDEs (eg Eclipse) come with their own compiler and will run in a JRE-only situation.

Comment: Start your application, then run `jconsole`, and look at the VM summary tab. Also check your `JAVA_HOME` and path settings. You may have another JRE installed that's being used instead of your JDK.

Comment: I use eclipse and I changed the .ini file to use JDK instead of JRE but still not working.

Comment: You need to change the run configuration. you may also need to install the JDK under Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and set the JDK as the default

Answer (score 1):

That is because of CXF using JRE7 instead of JDK7. When you install JDK in windows, by default JRE also installed and all preferences are pointed to JRE.

1. Check your PATH. Make sure it is pointed to ${JDK_LOCATION}/bin
2. Check your JAVA_HOME. Make sure it is pointed to ${JDK_LOCATION}
3. Go to control panel/java. Add JDK on it.
4. You also need to check eclipse in Window->Preference->Java->Installed JREs